# Triple Fault после перехода в защищенный режим

Tags: ассемблер, nasm, osdev

Пишу свою ОС и пока все выглядит так:

1. Загружается первый загрузчик, который загружает второй
2. Второй загрузчик должен включить A20, загрузить GDT, и перейти в защищенный режим

Я выяснил, что ошибка происходит во время перехода к 32-битному коду.

Мой код:

- Второй загрузчик

```
        jmp main
    
    %include "a20_line.asm"
    
    main:
        cli                 ; Set registers
        mov bp, 0x8000
        mov sp, bp
        mov ax, 0x0800
        mov ds, ax
        mov es, ax
        sti
        cld
    
        call enable_a20    
        call switch_pm
    
        jmp $

    %include "gdt.asm"
    %include "switch_pm.asm"
```

- Переход в защищенный режим (switch_pm.asm)

```
[bits 16]
switch_pm:
    cli                     ; Disable all interrupts

    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]   ; Load GDT Descriptor

    mov eax, cr0
    or al, 0x1             ; Set 32-bit mode bit in cr0
    mov cr0, eax
    
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm   ; <-- Здесь моя проблема

[bits 32]
init_pm:
    jmp $
```

- gdt.asm

```
gdt_start:
    dd 0x0 ; 4 byte
    dd 0x0 ; 4 byte

gdt_code: 
    dw 0xffff    ; segment length, bits 0-15
    dw 0x0       ; segment base, bits 0-15
    db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 16-23
    db 10011010b ; flags (8 bits)
    db 11001111b ; flags (4 bits) + segment length, bits 16-19
    db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 24-31

gdt_data:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0

gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 ; size (16 bit)
    dd gdt_start; address (32 bit)

CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

Если посмотреть на содержимое регистров (`info registers` в qemu), то содержимое `gdtr` такое: `GDT= 00000088 00000017` (код загружается по адресу `0x8000`). Я думаю, что из-за этого возникает ошибка, потому что в [примере](https://github.com/HazemGabr232/Simple_OS), который я использовал, загрузка GDT производится в загрузочном секторе и содержимое `gdtr` выглядит так: `GDT= 00007ccd 00000017` и `7ccd` соответствует положению таблицы в памяти, в моем же случае видимо должно быть так: `GDT= 00008088 00000017`. Добавление `0x8000` к `gdt_start` не помогает.

Из-за чего это и как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас наслоилось две ошибки - обе вызваны тем, что вы используете разные сегменты.

Без директивы `org`, ассемблер считает, что код будет загружен по адресу 0. Вы устанавливаете сегмент `DS` на `0x8000`, чтобы скомпенсировать это. Вот только дескриптор `GDT` должен содержать линейный адрес, а не сегментный. Ассемблер, однако, этого не знает, и пишет туда сегментный адрес. Т.е. `gdt_start` на `0x8000` меньше нужного.

После этого возникает другая проблема: `jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm` переходит к другому сегменту - `CS.base=0`. Однако ассемблер всё ещё считает адреса от сегмента `0x8000`. Т.е. адрес `init_pm` опять на `0x8000` меньше положенного. Более того - все адреса в 32-битном коде тоже будут неправильные!

Самый простой способ всё исправить - перевести всё в сегмент `0`: установить `DS=ES=0`, и написать `[org 0x8000]` в начале. В этом случае, ассемблер начнёт считать адреса с `0x8000` и ничего прибавлять будет не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что ты в switcher_pm.asm указываешь `jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm`, где в init_pm ты "зависаешь". У меня похожая проблема, только переключатель в защищенный режим не работает вообще. Попробуй заменить вот так[image: введите сюда описание изображения], где use32 замените на директиву своего ассемблера(bits 32)